# Notice: Undefined variable: dbname

Tags: php, mysql, session

Notice: Undefined variable: dbname

username not found

i cant take username and password from mysql db, maybe you know what cat be the problem?

............................................................................................

**page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require ('sql_connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submitlogin'])){
  $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['usernameinput']);
  $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['passwordinput']);
    if($username == $dbname){
      if($password == $dbpass){
        $_SESSION['currentuser'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['currentaccesslevel'] = 5;
        echo "welcome back, " . $username;
      }
      else {
        showform('wrong password');
      }
    }
    else {
      showform("username not found");
    }
  }
  else {
    showform("please enter your username and password");
  }
  function showform($message){
  include ('form.php');
  echo $message;
}
exit();
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_data` WHERE `username`='$dbname' `password`='$dbpass'");
?>
```

.............................................................................................

**sql_connect.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("mysql connection is failure.");
mysql_select_db("users") or die("Database does not exists.");
?>
```

...............................................................................................
**form.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="page2.php" />
<input type="text" name="usernameinput" />
<input type="text" name="passwordinput" />
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submitlogin' />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

........................................................................................

Comment: `$dbname` is never declared. You should read a php manual and start with someting simple. Sorry if I'm gonna be rude but if you don't know about this error, you can't handle a project with db involved

Answer (score 2):

you must define `$dbname` before using them. In the above code the `$dbname` not defined and you are comparing it. thats why the error is coming.

```
if($username == $dbname){
if($password == $dbpass){
```

define them fisrt

```
$dbname = //some value;
$dbpass = //some value;

if($username == $dbname){
if($password == $dbpass){
```

Comment: or declare them in `sql_connect.php`

Comment: i'v got to take username and password from mysql

Comment: the fetch them from db and assign them.